# Python Shapely Install Not working?

Tags: python, installation, anaconda, shapely

any thoughts?  I've tried uninstalling Shapely and installing with PIP
I have Anaconda and installed Fiona fine and Shapely seemingly fine.
Simple code:

```
import fiona
import shapely

dirVar = "C:\\Users\\me\\Desktop\\geocode\\"

with fiona.open(dirVar + "Regions.shp") as fiona_collection:

    shapefile_record = fiona_collection.next()
    shape = shapely.geometry.asShape(shapefile_record['geometry']) #GET ERROR HERE

    point = shapely.geometry.Point(32.398516, -39.754028) # longitude, latitude

    if shape.contains(point):
        print "Found shape for point."
```

> AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'geometry'

When I look at the methods of shapely from Wing IDE I see only:

```
ctypes_declarations
ftools
geos
```

I would think I should see geometry if it was installed correctly?

Any thoughts?

Comment: Try 'from shapely import geometry' in you import statement

Comment: @ anyone I am also using Anaconda but I am unable to install `shapely` using the `pip` command. The command prompt returns `Windows error: specified module cannot be found`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You could use one of these:

```
import shapely.geometry
```

or

```
from shapely import geometry
```