# module 'shapely' has no attribute 'geometry' error

Tags: python, python-import, attributeerror, shapely

I'm using Clint Harris' solution from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7861196/check-if-a-geopoint-with-latitude-and-longitude-is-within-a-shapefile)

```
import fiona
import shapely

with fiona.open("./areas_shp.shp") as fiona_collection:
    shapefile_record = next(iter(fiona_collection))
    shape = shapely.geometry.asShape( shapefile_record['geometry'] )
    point = shapely.geometry.Point(coords[0])
    for point in coords:
        if (shape.contains(point)):
            print("yay")
```

Here I'm just testing one coordinate with a shapefile, but it appears the code may be out of date. I changed `shapefile_record = fiona_collection.next()` to `shapefile_record = next(iter(fiona_collection))` already but this error I cannot seem to solve:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
AttributeError                            Traceback (most recent call last)
<ipython-input-8-18ca8979d01f> in <module>
     38 with fiona.open("./areas_shp.shp") as fiona_collection:
     39     shapefile_record = next(iter(fiona_collection))
---> 40     shape = shapely.geometry.asShape( shapefile_record['geometry'] )
     41     point = shapely.geometry.Point(coords[0])
     42     for point in coords:

AttributeError: module 'shapely' has no attribute 'geometry'
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Python Shapely Install Not working?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35978649/python-shapely-install-not-working)

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Your code is searching for geometry attribute in shapely module and it is failing.
To solve this, import the `shapely.geometry` module as below.

```
import shapely.geometry

shape = shapely.geometry.asShape( shapefile_record['geometry'])
```